# admin_post_(action) hook create console log error

Tags: hooks, wp-debug

In latest WordPress if web page has `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="action_name">` input field with name=action then it create console log error. But this happen maybe 4.9.5/6.

However. if page has form or just `<form></form>` tag before that input field (name=action) then console error not generate.

[admin_post_(action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)) require to used field with `name="action"` and when use this field with certain name value this error generate infinitely on only console error ***`Uncaught TypeError: e.action.indexOf is not a function`***.

[image]

Is it a WordPress bug or is there anyway I can avoid this error.

Currently I avoiding this error using extra form before it.

Comment: on which hook do you create this form ?

Comment: Those are JavaScript errors, in whatever 'onloadwff.js' is. Nothing to do with any PHP hooks. A quick search shows that `onloadwff.js` is part of the LastPass browser extension. Are you using an input outside of a form element?

Comment: Thanks Jacob and Lastpass was the culprit here. Thanks again.